# evaluate $\lim(1+3x)^{(1/2x)}$.

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Evaluate $\lim(1+3x)^{(1/2x)}$ as x approches 0

We know that :

$\lim(1+x)^{(1/x)} =e$ "as x approaches 0 "

I know that we can manipulate this equation to get **$e$** to some power

and I tried so many times to get it but I didn't.

Curious to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$(1+3x)^{1/(2x)} = \left((1+3x)^{1/(3x)}\right)^{3/2} = \left( (1+y)^{1/y}\right)^{3/2}$$
where $y=3x$. Now conclude what you want.

Comment: Very interesting way of doing it, was not my approach but it is much quicker. Good work

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Simple and more helpful.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that is a bit more involved

$$
(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{2x}} = e^{\ln(1+3x)/2x} \therefore
$$
As x approaches 0, you must now find a value for

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\ln(1+3x)}{2x}} = ?
$$
knowing the definition:

$$
ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k (-1)^{k-1}}{k}
$$

$$
\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(3x)^k(-1)^{k-1}}{2kx}
$$

Since $x \rightarrow 0$ all other terms will be zero, therefore

$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{2x}} = e^{\frac{3}{2}}
$

Comment: Love this approach, btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}$

Then  $$\ln{(y)}=(\frac{1}{2x})\ln{(1+3x)}\\= \frac{\ln{(1+3x)}}{2x}$$
Now \begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\ln{(y)}&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+3x})}{2x} \\&=\underbrace{ \bigg[\frac{0}{0}\bigg]}_\text{Indeterminate form}\end{align}
Thus we make use of L'Hospital's Rule
\begin{align} \lim_{x \to 0}\ln{(y)}\\ &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{3}{1+3x}}{2}\\ &= \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3}{1+3x}) \\&=\frac{3}{2}\end{align}

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}y &= \lim_{x\to 0}e^{\ln{(y)}} \\ &= e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\ln{(y)}} \\ &= e^{\frac{3}{2}}\end{align}

Comment: the derivative of $\frac{ln(1+3x)}{2x}$ does not equal $\frac{\frac{1}{3x+1}}{2}$

Comment: @EricLawson - Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to write the 3 in numerator, which messed everything else up. Fixed it

Comment: that is still not the derivative

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{ln(1+3x)}{2x} = \frac{3}{2x+6x^2}-\frac{ln(3x+1)}{2x^2}
$$

Comment: When using L'Hospital, you derive numerator and denomenator seperately. $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

Comment: oh that was why I didn't get the right answer using this approach haha, been a while since I have used this rule.

Comment: Hehe! All good! :) :) .